Discrepancy in API response times between Newman and Allure reports
I am using Newman to test APIs and generating reports using Allure. I have noticed that there is a consistent difference in the reported response times between Newman and Allure. For example, Newman shows a response time of around 400ms, but in Allure, it shows around 450ms, consistently a 30-50ms difference in all the requests.
I have checked the documentation for both Newman and Allure but couldn't find any specific explanation for this difference.
Could someone please explain why this difference might occur and how I can ensure more accurate reporting of response times in my tests?
